# Button clicks to add GridViews inside TabContainer

Tags: c#, design-patterns

I have a program which is primarily illustrative in example to help me learn refactoring techniques and best practices.  This program will take the `ActiveTabIndex` property of a `TabContainer` control and add a `GridView` control to the page and bind it to a database using a stored procedure.  Each tab in the `TabContainer` will be bound to a different stored procedure with the tab that is clicked on being the event that creates the `GridView` and does the binding.  I know that I have too much repeated code, but I'm not sure how to rectify it.

I thought about maybe having a method that takes the stored procedure name as a parameter and appends the `ActiveTabIndex` to the stored procedure name, but that seems just about as tightly coupled and tenuous at best.  What are some methods I can employ to reduce the amount of duplicated code I have?

```
  public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
  {    
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        protected void btnMakeGridView_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string cs = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["dbcs"].ConnectionString;
            if (TabContainer1.ActiveTabIndex == 0)
            {             
                using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cs))
                {
                    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("spTest0", con))
                    {
                        con.Open();
                        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                        SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                        GridView gv = new GridView();
                        TabContainer1.Tabs[TabContainer1.ActiveTabIndex].Controls.Add(gv);
                        gv.DataSource = rdr;
                        gv.DataBind();

                    }
                }
            }
            else if (TabContainer1.ActiveTabIndex == 1)
            {
                using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cs))
                {
                    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("spTest1", con))
                    {
                        con.Open();
                        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                        SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                        GridView gv = new GridView();
                        TabContainer1.Tabs[TabContainer1.ActiveTabIndex].Controls.Add(gv);
                        gv.DataSource = rdr;
                        gv.DataBind();

                    }
                }
            }
            else if (TabContainer1.ActiveTabIndex == 2)
            {
                using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cs))
                {
                    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("spTest2", con))
                    {
                        con.Open();
                        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                        SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                        GridView gv = new GridView();
                        TabContainer1.Tabs[TabContainer1.ActiveTabIndex].Controls.Add(gv);
                        gv.DataSource = rdr;
                        gv.DataBind();

                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Label1.Text = "You must select a tab to create the GridView in";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My full intentions were to dynamically build the number of tabs as well based on how much *different* stored procedures the user selected.  I think using the stored procedure name as a tag property would be how I would make the correct `GridView` to the correct `TabPanel`.  I apologize if my given example seems too far off from my original intent.  I wanted to make sure that I was at least somewhat on the right track before I gave a small code snippet and asked for the moon.

Maybe something like "select name from `sys.procedures`" where name like '%ProcsToChoose%', create a `List<string>` out of that and give the query a `row_number()` -1 to bind to the ordinal index (but that seems like a poor idea) of the `TabPanel`.

Attempt at streamlining code:

```
protected void btnMakeGridView_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TabContainer1.Tabs[TabContainer1.ActiveTabIndex].Controls.Add(GetData(cs, "spTest", TabContainer1.ActiveTabIndex));
}

public static GridView GetData(string connectionString,string spName, int activeIndex)
{
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(spName, con))
        {
            con.Open();
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            GridView gv = new GridView();
            gv.ID = "gv" + activeIndex.ToString();
            gv.DataSource = rdr;
            gv.DataBind();
            return gv;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Save "spTest0", "spTest1", "spTest2", etc. as a `Tag` property of a `Tab`. Get the active tab, get its tag, convert that to string and use it as a stored procedure name. Once you know the sp name - the rest of the code is the same, so no need for repetitive if statements. The only real problem is - how do you map tab object / tab index to a stored procedure name? Using Tag property is one way; having an array of stored procedure names where array index corresponds to tab index is another. You could also map tab name to stored proc name with a dictionary. There are many ways to skin this cat.

Comment: Hello, thanks for the reply.  Please refer to the edit for the changes that I made in trying to make this more extensible (please let me know if this is the right track).  I felt it would have been too ambitious to state what I really wanted to do without really knowing how close to the right track I was so please check the edit for further info.

Comment: Sounds like you want your UI to be completely SQL-driven. The app would know how to log in to the database, and the UI will be built after some interrogation of the table contents. And if the SQL connection fails, then the UI will be almost blank. The advantage of putting it all in SQL is that you do not have to hard-code some data in the db and some data in the UI. Things I do not like are: 1) Do not rely on stored procedure names. I would list them explicitly in a separate table. Also, are tabs the answer? If tabs look very much alike, then differentiate between sources using a combo box?

Comment: @Leonid this is as much as anything just an exercise in practice.  I'm not tied or married to any particular design, just trying to learn.

Comment: ok ... why not aim high? If you want to succeed as a programmer, you need to be very good - good at writing and refactoring code, good at making and refactoring GUI, good at writing clear documentation ... It also helps to work on real problems. You can get the computer do just about anything for you. It is important to work on something that somebody would need because you learn about tradeoffs that you are often forced to make. Anyhow, if you share the screenshot of what your GUI looks like, I can offer some GUI refactoring advice.

Answer (score 2):

Leonid's comments cover structure nicely, so I will tackle stylistic points (working off your streamlined edit).

**Naming**

Avoid shortened form variable names. Extra characters on a variable's name are free, and work wonders for a maintenance programmer down the line.

e.g.

```
SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
```

would better be:

```
SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
```

**Var**

Use the `var` keyword when defining local variables where the right hand side of the definition makes the type obvious. This looks cleaner and saves time when it comes to changing types during refactoring.

e.g.

```
using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(spName, con))
```

should be

```
using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(spName, con))
```

**Magic Strings**

It looks like you have a couple of magic strings (e.g. "gv" and "spTest") in your code that would be better off refactored into constants with descriptive names.

**Misc**

It looks like you can get rid of the declaration of 'rdr' and simply use:

```
gv.DataSource = (SqlDataReader)cmd.ExecuteReader();
```